# How to properly publish an AMD module so that RequireJS can locate the dependencies?

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd

AMD is my favorite JS module standard, for the simple reason that it allows the proper specification of module dependencies in an analyzable way. Say my module uses `jquery` and `lodash`:

```
define(['jquery', 'lodash'], function ($, _) { ... });
```

Now, say I want to publish this module. Of course, I would specify those dependencies in the `package.json` and/or `bower.json` files, so I can be sure they will be installed. However, how can I be sure that the `jquery` and `lodash` libraries are found by the AMD loader (e.g. RequireJS)?

It seems that users of my library would be forced to specify those paths manually:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery-min',
        lodash: '../lib/lodash/dist/lodash'
    }
});
```

As an application developer, I would be fine with that. But
I cannot just assume that users of my library will automatically do this (let alone with matching names), so I'd have to document the extra step. This worries me. NodeJS / CommonJS seems to have a way of finding the correct file without any path specification. I'm not sure how this is done, but I guess they search in the most likely places.

What is the preferred way of handling this for AMD packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tutorial about how to build a standalone library with requirejs [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-library-with-requirejs/).

Also take a look at this [example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-libglobal).

Basically you wrap your code with a start and end code segments. And specify it in the config.

```
{
    "baseUrl": "../lib",
    "paths": {
        "principium": "../principium"
    },
    "include": ["../tools/almond", "principium"],
    "exclude": ["jquery", "underscore"],
    "out": "../dist/principium.js",
    "wrap": {
        "startFile": "wrap.start",
        "endFile": "wrap.end"
    }
}
```

Note that, you exclude the used libraries `jquery` and `underscore` because you expect users  of your library to include them for you. You tell your users about the dependencies. That is the recommended approach. Though you could omit the `exclude` and let the dependency be included in your build, that is fine as well.

Comment: That's not too bad, mostly because it is a 'standard' technique supported directly by the RequireJS developers themselves (through `r.js`). But I can't help but observe that it doesn't solve my original problem: This requires users of my library to specify the paths for all my dependencies (having to make sure they use the same names for them that I did). But perhaps it is acceptable if it is standard practice.

Comment: @mhelvens Your dependencies have a single known browser globals, such as $ for jquery and _ for underscore. However you can embed the dependencies just by omitting it in the `exclude` option. How else do you want to include the dependencies. You grab the globals in the wrapper files, see the [example-libglobal](https://github.com/requirejs/example-libglobal/blob/master/tools/wrap.start) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

RequireJS is just a module loader, not a dependency management system.

If you just want to provide the easiest level of integration (with minimal setup), then bundle the dependencies with your distribution. Don't require the use of dependency management systems such as npm or bower, but use a build script to generate a single file. Then export your module as if it is a single module. You can generate a self-contained module using the [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js) optimizer (and use [almond.js](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) as a minimal internal module loader if you don't use advanced features of Require.js).

The main disadvantage of the latter method is that the total size of the JavaScript code is often larger than your original method, because the user always loads your copy of jQuery, regardless of whether jQuery was already loaded before. An advantage is that you can easily swap out dependencies without asking the user to change their configuration.

If you don't want to inline the dependencies, then you could bundle the dependencies with your library, as follows (using `npm` as dependency manager, for example):

```
define(['./node_modules/lodash/lodash'], function(_) {
```

If the user wishes to override the dependency (e.g. to reduce file size of the final output after using a build tool), then they could use (assuming `npm` again):

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // replace yourmodule's lodash with lodash.js from the module's root
        'node_modules/yourmodule/node_modules/lodash/lodash': 'lodash'
    }
});
```

The last method has two disadvantages over the other methods:

1. It doesn't work with named modules, i.e. modules that are defined as `define('name', ...);`.
2. If you have multiple modules that use the dependency, and you move the dependency to a different folder, then you have to search and replace all explicit dependency paths.

Comment: Indeed; the point of the question was that the user would not need several copies of such common libraries. Your proposed solution is not ideal, but it has the virtue that it *works* without any extra action on the part of the user, but can still be optimized with such an extra action. Thanks! (I have to admit, I'm surprised a better solution hasn't been created for this yet.)

Comment: @mhelvens The proposed solution is still not perfect, see edit. jQuery uses a named define so that's already an issue for your case.

Comment: Hm... I'll have to play around to see if I can't work around that (such as with [bundles](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles)). But again... wow. Isn't this a very common use-case? I thought it was just me missing something obvious.